# How to Post to HTML Form two with Delphi Indy

Tags: html, delphi, post, indy, delphi-xe

I want to Post with Delphi XE10 Indy to Form 2 (name="voting_maybe") in following HTML code.

```
<form method="post" name="voting_yes" class="dtyrd-form" action="&#x2F;vote&#x2F;yes" id="voting_yes">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="dtyrd-button&#x20;dtyrd-button-voting&#x20;dtyrd-button-color-green" value=""><span class="image"></span>Yes</button>
</form>

<form method="post" name="voting_maybe" class="dtyrd-form" action="&#x2F;vote&#x2F;maybe" id="voting_maybe">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="dtyrd-button&#x20;dtyrd-button-voting&#x20;dtyrd-button-color-grey" value="Maybe"> 
</form>

<form method="post" name="voting_no" class="dtyrd-form" action="&#x2F;vote&#x2F;no" id="voting_no">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="dtyrd-button&#x20;dtyrd-button-voting&#x20;dtyrd-button-color-red" value="No">
</form>
```

I want to do this like:

```
PostStream := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
try
  PostStream.AddFormField('submit','submit');

  Response := HTTPClient.Post(url, PostStream);

finally
  PostStream.Free;
end;
```

But how can I send the Post to Form 2 (name="voting_maybe")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply populate a `TStringList` with `name=value` strings that are defined by the `<input>` fields of the `voting_maybe` webform, and then `Post()` to the URL specified by the `action` attribute of that webform.  Each `<form>` element is to be posted independently of any other `<form>` on the same page.

Do not use `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` in this situation, as your `<form>` elements do not have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on them.  Without an explicit `enctype`, the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is what the `TStrings` version of `Post()` uses.

For example:

```
PostData := TStringList.Create;
try
  PostData.Add('submit=Maybe');
  Response := HTTPClient.Post(baseurl+'/vote/maybe', PostData);
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;
```